# Is Sobolev limit of bijective maps surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega_1,\Omega_2 \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be open, connected, bounded, with non-empty $C^1$ boundaries. Let $f_n:\bar\Omega_1 \to \bar\Omega_2$ be $C^1$ be **bijective** maps with $\det(df_n)>0$, and suppose that $f_n$ converges to a continuous function $f: \bar\Omega_1 \to \bar\Omega_2$ strongly in $W^{1,2}$.

> **Question:** Must $f$ be surjective?

*Note that $f$ is surjective if and only if $|f^{-1}(y)| \le 1$ a.e. on $\Omega_2$:*

By the area formula
$$
 \int_{\Omega_1} \det df_n  = \int_{\Omega_2} |f_n^{-1}(y)|=\text{Vol}(\Omega_2),
$$
so
$$
\int_{\Omega_2} |f^{-1}(y)|= \int_{\Omega_1} \det df  =\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega_1} \det df_n=\text{Vol}(\Omega_2).
$$
This implies the claim.

Comment: I don't get how you are applying the area formula. You should have $$ \mathrm{Vol}(\Omega_2) = \int_{\Omega_2} 1 \cdot \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\Omega_1} \underbrace{1 \circ f_n(x)}_{= 1} \det \mathrm{d}f_n(x) ~\mathrm{d}x $$  Are you using $|f^{-1}(y)|$ to denote the Cardinality of the set $f^{-1}(y)$? If that case, surjectivity would also require $|f^{-1}(y) | \geq 1$ by definition, and hence you see that $f$ is surjective if and only if $|f^{-1}(y) | = 1$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Yes, exactly. $|f^{-1}(y)|$ denotes the cardinality of the set $f^{-1}(y)$. I agree with your conclusion. My point was only that in this case surjectivity and "almost everywhere injectivity on the codomain" imply each other.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for contradiction that $f$ misses a point $q\in\Omega_2.$ It must miss some neighborhood $U\subset \Omega_2$ of $q.$ Choose a bump function $\alpha$ with $\int \alpha=1$ whose support lies in $U.$

The Jacobians $\det f_n$ converge in $L^1$ to $\det df.$ The functions $\alpha\circ f_n$ are uniformly bounded and converge in measure to $\alpha\circ f.$
By the result at [Convergence in measure and $L_p$ implies product converges in $L_p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889536/convergence-in-measure-and-l-p-implies-product-converges-in-l-p?rq=1),

$$\int \alpha(f_n(x))\det df_n\to \int \alpha(f(x))\det df$$

The right hand side is zero because $\alpha\circ f\equiv 0.$ But by the change of variables formula along the orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms $f_n,$ the left hand side is $\int_{\Omega_2}\alpha = 1.$ This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very nice argument! One question: Do you need the assumption that $\det df$ is a bounded function for getting estimate $(2)$? I understand why  $\alpha\circ f_n$ converges to $\alpha\circ f$ in $L^1$. I am asking why this remains true after multiplying pointwise by $\det df$. If I am not mistaken, I think that you need to assume that $\det df$ is bounded for that. (I actually don't have a problem with this additional assumption; I just wanted to be sure if you are actually relying on it, implicitly).

Comment: Oh I think I get it now-you are using Holder's inequality: $\int |f_n-f| |Jf|\le \|f_n-f\|_{L^2} \|Jf\|_{L^2} \to 0$.

Comment: @AsafShachar: I was thinking $f$ was $C^1.$ I have added a link to a fact about product convergence that works without any assumption on $f.$ That Holder's inequality argument seems to need to assume $Jf$ is in $L^2.$

Comment: I wanted to thank you again for your great answer. I forgot to mention that I posted a cross-post on mathoverflow here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370461/is-sobolev-limit-of-bijective-maps-surjective . I think you can just copy your answer here to there, and I will accept it there as well.